# I can't retrieve data from the server in my client. (useTracker)

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to follow the basic documentation of MeteorJS and I have created a TaskCollection with mongo using:
`export const TasksCollection = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');`

I also populated the collection, and I can see the data is correctly inserted to the MongoDb.

In client:
`const tasks = useTracker(() => TasksCollection.find({}).fetch());`

But tasks still a empty array, but is not empty since the database is populated.

I have tried many things but nothing solved. I've tried to publish the collection but I'm not sure if its right.

Comment: Did you perhaps remove the `autopublish` package? If you're doing one of the earlier chapters, get it back using `meteor add autopublish`. If you wanted to remove it, you'll need to publish it manually from the server. My suggestion would be to 1) install the "Meteor DevTools Evolved" package for Chrome and then check the Subscriptions tab, 2) double-check that the data is actually in the database (you should install NoSQLBooster).

Comment: @vgru, thanks man autopublish worked :)